# How do I mock/spyOn exported functions from another file that isn't a node_module with Jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a function I'm trying to test...

```js
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  getAuth,
  UserCredential,
} from 'firebase/auth';

import {
  setFirestoreUserBudgetCollection,
  subscribeFirestoreServiceToUserBudgetItemCollectionStore,
} from '../firestore/FirestoreService';

export function signUpUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential> {
  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(firebaseApp), email, password).then(
    (credential: UserCredential) => {
      subscribeFirestoreServiceToUserBudgetItemCollectionStore();
      setFirestoreUserBudgetCollection(credential.user.uid, {});
      return Promise.resolve(credential);
    }
  );
}
```

I want to write a unit test to make sure my external functions get called and the Firebase library functions get called as expected. I wrote my unit test as such...

```js
import { subscribeFirestoreServiceToUserBudgetItemCollectionStore, setFirestoreUserBudgetCollection } from '../firestore/FirestoreService';
import { signUpUser } from './AuthService';

jest.mock('firebase/auth');
jest.mock('../firestore/FirestoreService', () => ({
  setFirestoreUserBudgetCollection: jest.fn(),
  subscribeFirestoreServiceToUserBudgetItemCollectionStore: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('auth - ', () => {
  test('signUpUser', () => {
    (createUserWithEmailAndPassword as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue({ user: { uid: 1234 } });
    signUpUser('email', 'password');
    expect(createUserWithEmailAndPassword as jest.Mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.any(Object),
      'email',
      'password'
    );
    expect(
      subscribeFirestoreServiceToUserBudgetItemCollectionStore as jest.Mock
    ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(setFirestoreUserBudgetCollection as jest.Mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

It works great to spy and check that the `firebase/auth` node_module functions get called, but not the file I made `FirestoreService`....which just looks like this....

```js
export function subscribeFirestoreServiceToUserBudgetItemCollectionStore(): void {
...
}

export function setFirestoreUserBudgetCollection(): Promise<void> {
...
}
```

I've tried some ideas I've found googling like making a `__mocks__` directory and stubbing out the `FirestoreService` that way but no luck. I'm not understanding and running in circles, need some help.

Comment: Hi. Looks like you may have forgotten the `await` before `signUpUser` in your test?

Comment: Agh you're right, kept overthinking the mocking. Thanks!

Comment: Happened to me so many times :)